# mysql data truncated with ñ character

Tags: mysql

I'm uploading data from a local file to a data base in MySQL in my server.

so I'm using the following commands:

```
mysql -u dude --password --local-infile
use rest_db;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/scripts/asistencia.txt' INTO TABLE asistencia FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

So I get:

```
Query OK, 765 rows affected, 15 warnings (0.01 sec)
Records: 765  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 15
```

The warnings are:

```
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                      |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'nombre' at row 76 |
```

But when I check the records from my local PHPMYADMIN I see that these fields are not showing the "ñ" characters instead I get  "Ã±" characters.

I tried setting this field (VARCHAR) to "utf8_spanish2_ci" or "utf8_spanish2_ci" or "latin1_spanish_ci" but the behavior is the same.

Any hint of what I'm missing?

By the way the record is: "AVENDAñO" but I get in the DB "AVENDAÃ±O"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the truncated warnings are due to the special characters. I think you are getting that because the column you are importing into has too short of a length for those 15 records. You probably just need to increase the length of the column.

These types of encoding issues can get complex when dealing with different character sets. In these cases, just changing the collation will not fix the problem, you need to change the `CHARSET` as @hd1 mentioned. Only after changing the `CHARSET` should you worry about the collation.

**Just to be safe, export your database/table before altering it.**

I would begin, by converting the table to `utf8` since it is now the standard.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

By doing this, it will also change the `CHARSET` of the table and columns to utf8, but you may still need to manually change the collation of the columns to `utf8_general_ci` (default). In the event `utf8_general_ci` doesn't contain the specific characters, you can use `utf8_spanish_ci`

In the event you want to change the default character set (for new columns)...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Here is some helpful documentation:

[10.1 Character Set Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html)
[10.1.12 Column Character Set Conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html)
[10.1.13.1 Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Comment: weird thing; I have the correct character now (ñ) but get the same warning... guess it is some kind of bug.

Comment: For the truncated warnings, you are probably getting it because your column isn't a sufficient length. Check that fore sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you Update the table (from PHP) like below the problem will fix:

```
Update table_name
   set col_name=replace(col_name,'Ã±','ñ')
```

also at importing time you can do it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/scripts/asistencia.txt' INTO TABLE asistencia FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' set col_name=replace(col_name,'Ã±','ñ');
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying  to set an automated task for this upload files in DB. So I try to avoid these problems from the beginning instead of fixing them later. Thats why I try to eliminate the "Warnings" and the "Truncated field" issue. :)

Comment: great, you can do this immediately after loading data into table :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a [default collation of latin1_swedish_ci](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/138/Default+MySQL+character+set+and+collation#gs). To set a new collation, you need to issue an `ALTER DATABASE foo DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8' DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'` command, but this will not update preexisting entries. So, I'd [dump a flatfile](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/), edit it and [reload it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.0/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html) using `mysql < dumpfile.sql`. The mysqldump command produces a text file which may be edited in, e.g., [vim](http://www.vim.org) with no trouble.

Hope this helps. If you have further issues, do leave a comment.

Comment: When changing the default char set to utf8, mysql will automatically assign collation `utf8_general_ci`. I believe if he uses the same statement you provided with `ALTER TABLE` he may not need to dump the data.

Comment: I do believe you're mistaken. `ALTER TABLE` is a forward-looking statement. It should not alter existing data, which is why the dump is necessary.

Comment: The particular statement you gave won't convert the existing data, but you can in fact convert it with `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: This worked, since I have few data that I could reload easily, I DROPED then ALTER table, after I reload data I have no data truncated but still have the warning! ...weird, but now works...